# tengo un error al loguearme -> These credentials do not match our records.LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

No se en que parte es lo que estoy enviando mal, mas que agradecida por la ayuda.

Este es el modelo de usuario, estoy llamando a una tabla llamada ingreso

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $table = 'ingreso';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_usuario';

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function registro()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Registro::class , 'id_registro');
    }
```

Este es el controlador para login, aquí solo aumenté la función username para que me valide ese campo de mi tabla

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
```

Comment: Hola, el error más que nada te está diciendo que ya sea el usuario o contraseña no son las correctas, Si recién acabas de crear la estructura con *php artisan make:auth*, no deberías tener problemas en el código. Registra otro usuario y ve si te sale lo mismo. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Sebastian si corrí el php artisan make:auth. Lo que pasa es que tengo que poner otros campos y es por eso que en el modelo usuario le protejo esa nueva tabla ... y he cambiado los campos .... cuando ingreso datos si me guarda en la base de datos ... pero al querer ingresas en el login no me reconoce, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Buenas, si no tienes mucha experiencia con laravel, es mejor que sigas la documentación oficial de laravel para hacer el login.

Comment: Hay algo que no me cuadra, si la tabla es **User**, en su modelo **User.php** el **protected $table** debería ser **protected $table = 'user';** no lo que tienes puesto en tu caso, ¿tienes un modelo para una tabla que se llame **ingreso**? A menos que tu hayas cambiado eso de las tablas. Puedes mostrarnos las tablas que están relacionadas con el Usuario y tu ingreso? Gracias

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo que pasa es que estaba intentando con otras tablas.

Answer (score -1):

seguramente cuando haces el nuevo registro, estas omitiendo el encriptar la contraseña con el helper bcrypt, recuerda que el Auth de laravel para Autenticar usa Hash, y el requisito es que la contraseña este encriptada.

Comment: esa encriptación ya viene por defecto en el controlador

Comment: Gracias lo tendré en cuenta